# Suspicious Operation trying to upload local image to S3 in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models

I'm developing a Django project where my Users have a profile picture saved as an ImageField, which I currently store in S3.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to=get_user_pic_path)

def get_user_pic_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('user_pics', instance.user.username, filename)
```

with the relevant `settings.py`:

```
# Amazon S3 stuff
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

# URL prefix for static files.
STATIC_ROOT = '/%s/' % AWS_LOCATION
STATIC_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

# Media urls
MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
MEDIA_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

The project works in production, which allows users to create accounts by taking a webcam photo and saving that to S3, but I get a `SuspiciousOperation` when trying to set up a local user for testing purposes. I have a command that is invoked by `python manage.py create_test_user`, which does:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    pic_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'img', 'test_img.jpg')

    user_list, pic_list = [], []
    for i in range(5):
        # create user objects associated with each MyUser
        u = User.objects.create_user(
            username='bickeree_'+str(i),
            email=str(i)+'@gmail.com',
            password='1234'
        )
        u.first_name = 'Test User'
        u.last_name = str(i)
        u.save()

        # we store the picture so we can properly close it
        pic_list.append(File(open(pic_path, 'rb')))
        user_list.append(MyUser(
            user=u,
            picture=pic_list[-1],
        ))

    # create all of the MyUser objects
    MyUser.objects.bulk_create(user_list)

    # clean up the images
    for pic in pic_list:
        pic.close()
```

Running this command results in:

```
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '/Users/username/Documents/projectname/static/img/test_img.jpg' denied.
```

How to get around this error?

Comment: do you have the full trace so we know which line causes the error?